# Mis-using managed identities for Azure resources

Tags: azure-managed-identity

I have some VM's with managed identities to allow them to access azure key vaults, as per current best practice.

An operator can log into the VM though, and issue connect to Azure using something like

`Connect-AzAccount -Identity`

And then query the key vault with that context.  Is there a way of stopping this? It seems a bit of a security flaw.

Thanks